# How do you estimate a linear trend in prevalence?

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have a survey that is done quarterly, and in each quarter participants are asked whether they smoke or not. Here is the data:

```
d <- structure(list(quarter = 1:72, smoker = c(13575L, 917L, 891L, 
                                               933L, 1111L, 1104L, 1056L, 1111L, 1127L, 1236L, 1189L, 1136L, 
                                               1279L, 1107L, 1244L, 1195L, 1324L, 1364L, 1419L, 1409L, 1498L, 
                                               1404L, 1341L, 1338L, 1549L, 1400L, 1522L, 1384L, 1589L, 1413L, 
                                               1381L, 1447L, 1464L, 1491L, 1611L, 1431L, 1558L, 1470L, 1553L, 
                                               1489L, 1469L, 1395L, 1541L, 1476L, 1494L, 1440L, 1490L, 1410L, 
                                               1484L, 1408L, 1466L, 1349L, 1512L, 1460L, 1461L, 1389L, 1418L, 
                                               1409L, 1379L, 1271L, 1295L, 1244L, 1216L, 1139L, 1196L, 1278L, 
                                               1161L, 1227L, 1261L, 1272L, 1301L, 464L), nonsmoker = c(20169L, 
                                                                                                       1365L, 1358L, 1336L, 1538L, 1463L, 1658L, 1683L, 1750L, 1741L, 
                                                                                                       1779L, 1690L, 1978L, 1779L, 1907L, 1826L, 2108L, 2178L, 2177L, 
                                                                                                       2338L, 2567L, 2341L, 2341L, 2339L, 2522L, 2469L, 2726L, 2586L, 
                                                                                                       2882L, 2603L, 2655L, 2449L, 2638L, 2644L, 3075L, 2760L, 2996L, 
                                                                                                       2772L, 2801L, 2702L, 2695L, 2575L, 2706L, 2541L, 2750L, 2817L, 
                                                                                                       2735L, 2569L, 2667L, 2521L, 2814L, 2466L, 2693L, 2607L, 2977L, 
                                                                                                       2472L, 2597L, 2539L, 2635L, 2361L, 2383L, 2268L, 2308L, 2170L, 
                                                                                                       2216L, 2356L, 2459L, 2310L, 2416L, 2465L, 2501L, 894L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -72L))
```

I am trying to estimate the linear trend. One approach is to use a logistic model:

```
# calculate the prevalence in each quarter
d$total <- d$smoker + d$nonsmoker
d$prev <- d$smoker / d$total

# use a logistic model to estimate a trend line
model1 <- glm(cbind(smoker, nonsmoker) ~ quarter, data = d, family = 'binomial')
d$predicted <- predict(model1, newdata = d, type = 'response')

# plot
plot(d$quarter, d$prev, ylim = c(0, 0.5))
lines(d$quarter, d$predicted)
```

[image]

However, this approach does not estimate a linear trend, but a log-linear trend. This is not obvious on the chart because the curve is quite gentle, but there is a curve.

We could use a linear model using the prevalence rather than the actual data:

```
# linear model using prevalence
model2 <- lm(prev ~ quarter, data = d)
d$predicted2 <- predict(model2, newdata = d, type = 'response')

# add to plot in red
lines(d$quarter, d$predicted2, col = 'red')
```

This gives almost identical results so isn't a great example! But the line is straight, rather than curved. This is what I want, but I think the standard error of this model is wrong because it uses the prevalence rather than the raw data.

[image]

How do I estimate the linear trend correctly?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? You've fitted a couple of models to the data but I don't get what you dislike about them (especially the logistic), or why you are certain that the response should be a straight line.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not certain it should be a straight line, but that's the assumption I'd like to make. The point estimate for the linear model seems OK, but I think the standard error is wrong because it doesn't account for the standard error of the prevalence at each point in time.

Comment: It is not reasonable to assume that a non-flat trend is linear.  I'd fit the long-term trend using a spline function, and consider adding cyclic trends.  An example is given here: https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#complex-curve-fitting-example

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your comment; I'm a long-term admirer of your work and have learnt a lot from you. What if we have a good prior reason to think that the prevalence is reducing in a linear way; and we want to measure the linear trend? Of course if the observed data are wildly non-linear that would be silly, but in this case it doesn't seem silly?